# Average rate of water dripping from a cylindrical bucket

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume, related-rates

Water drips out of the bottom of a cylindrical bucket that is initially full. The rate of dripping is proportional to the height of water column in the bucket. If the rate of dripping at half height is R, then the average rate of dripping until the bucket becomes almost empty is:

1.greater than R

2.R

3. Between R/2 and R

4. Less than R/2

How to find the average rate of dripping, please help. Thanks in advance.

*My attempt* (Modified as per my trivial understanding of the comments)

Let $$V=\pi r^2 h$$
The rate of water dripping from the bucket is:
$$-\frac{dV}{dt}=\pi r^2 \frac{dh}{dt}$$
Now we have $-\frac{dV}{dt}=kh$ for some constant of proportional $k$.
Also for half height we have $R=kH/2$ which gives $k=2R/H$. Substituting back we get:
$-\frac{dV}{dt}= 2Rh/H$
When the bucket becomes almost empty, the instantaneous rate is: $-\frac{dV}{dt}= 2R$
But I need to find the *average* rate of dripping.
Is it the right way to do it?
What should I do next, please suggest.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I have added my attempt, please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful to distinguish between the height $H$ of the bucket and the height $h$ of the water in the bucket.

Comment: In addition to the problem that N. F. Taussig has pointed out, note that as the water drips out, the volume $V$ of water in the bucket *decreases*, so $\frac{dV}{dt} < 0$. The rate of dripping is the change in the amount of water exiting the bucket with time, not the change in the amount of water in the bucket with time.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thank you for pointing out, I am new to such problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite simple after you get the differential equation in terms of R. Let us first define the equations properly. You have:
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -kh$$
Where h is the height of water **inside** the bucket at any time. (Note that when your bucket becomes *almost* empty h is very close to 0. So your rate is negligible. Your conclusion of instantaneous rate = 2R is a result of another confusion, I'm afraid)

H is the maximum height, also the height at t=0 (convince yourself it cannot become greater than height at t=0 formally)

The differential equation has a solution of the form $$h = C\exp\{-kt\}$$
for some constant C.

From the condition of rate at half-full, you have $k = \frac{2R}{H}$ and since at t=0 height must be H, we have $H = C.e^0 \implies C=H$. So you finally have
$$h = H\exp\{-\frac{2Rt}{H}\}$$

Intuitively, this bucket will be always remain full as the function asymptotically approaches 0(i.e., it will be 0 only when time $t\rightarrow \infty$). So your average rate(i.e., $\frac{H}{\text{total time}}$) should be very very low with respect to R.

If you get this part, you just have to prove this formally. There are many ways to do this. I'll take an intuitive approach:

Observe that we need the same time, $\Delta t$, to reach from h1 and h1/2, for any $h1 \in (0,H]$:

By modifying(take log and multiply stuff) the general equation of h we get the time taken to reach any height is

$$t = \frac{H}{2R}ln(\frac{H}{h})$$

Hence we know the difference of times to reach h1 and h1/2:

$$\Delta t = \frac{H}{2R}ln(\frac{2H}{2h1}) - \frac{H}{2R}ln(\frac{H}{h1}) =\frac{H}{2R}ln(2)$$

The above property is sometimes called memorylessness and is quite important in many places.

Let us assume almost empty to be one-sixteenth(roughly 5%) of the original volume(and since it is proportional to height, one-sixteenth of its original height).

The average rate is the ratio of total height covered to total time taken to cover it. So I can write it like this:

$$R_{avg} = \frac{\frac{H}{2} + \frac{H}{4} + ...\frac{H}{2^n} }{n(\Delta t)}$$

$$ = \frac{H(1-\frac{1}{2^n})}{n. \frac{H}{2R}ln(2)}$$
$$ = \frac{(1-\frac{1}{2^n}). R}{nln(2)}$$

This obviously goes to 0 as n goes to infinity, but we assumed 1/16th of the original height to be *almost* empty. Plug in n=4 here to get 0.33R which is less than R/2.

Comment: You can format many of most common function names in mathjax simply by preceding them with a backslash. This clues in the processor to treat them appropriately, including any spacing between them and other symbols. For example, `n\ln 2` produces $n\ln 2$, as opposed to $nln 2$ without a backslash.

Comment: It doesn't take as much analysis as you've given here to figure out the correct answer. All you need to determine is that the bucket does not finish draining in a finite amount of time, which follows from the exponential equation. At that point, the average dripping rate is the total change of Volume (which cannot be any higher than the total volume of the bucked) divided by the total time, which by your decision on what counts as "almost empty" can be taken as long as you like. So you have bounded quantity divided by an unbounded one. It can be made as small as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but the answer is option (2) $R$ as per the solution key. (P.S. It was asked in CSIR NET 2019)

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha You do realise that even with the bucket only 3/4th's empty, the average rate will be much less than R? Are you sure about this? I think even Paul agrees that the rate will go to 0.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes you could end the answer there, but the people posing the question might use some abstract definition of 'almost empty'(as can be seen by the surprising answer), so I gave an intuitive way to figure it out for some general ratio. (Or the key might have some typos?)

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha - either you have incorrectly reproduced the problem here, or that answer is obviously wrong. As I noted in my second comment above, the bucket never entirely drains, so the time it takes to be "nearly empty" can be taken as large as desired. But the volume of water passing through is limited. For any reasonable definition of "almost empty", their ratio, the average rate of drippage, will be very close to $0$.